# Can't get a numerical value for this vector operation

Tags: syntax, vector, numerical-value

I have written these codes:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

r = (6.3674447) (10^6);
θm = (90 - 21.43) Degree;
φm = 39.82 Degree;
θe = (90 - 56.85) Degree;
φe = 60.6 Degree;

RM = {r Sin[θm] Cos[φm] , r Sin[θm] Sin[φm], r Cos[θm]};
RE = {r Sin[θe] Cos[φe] , r Sin[θe] Sin[φe], r Cos[θe]};

Q = FullSimplify[RM - RE];

x = {-Sin[φe], Cos[φe], 0};
y = {-Cos[θe] Cos[φe], -Cos[θe] Sin[φe], Sin[θe]};
z = x × y;

sol = N[FullSimplify[({Q·x, Q·y, Q·z}·y)/Norm[Q]]];

ArcCos[sol]
```

But at last I get:

[image: Result]

While everything is numerical and computable.

What's gone wrong?

---

EDIT:

For ones who may worry about code mistype (i.e. using dot instead of ·), here is my pure code (I didn't replace anything):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

r = (6.3674447) (10^6);
θm = (90 - 21.43) Degree;
ϕm = 39.82 Degree;
θe = (90 - 56.85) Degree;
ϕe = 60.6 Degree;

RM = {r Sin[θm] Cos[ϕm] , r Sin[θm] Sin[ϕm], r Cos[θm]};
RE = {r Sin[θe] Cos[ϕe] , r Sin[θe] Sin[ϕe], r Cos[θe]};

Q = FullSimplify[RM - RE];

x = {-Sin[ϕe], Cos[ϕe], 0};
y = {-Cos[θe] Cos[ϕe], -Cos[θe] Sin[ϕe], Sin[θe]};
z = x\[Cross]y;

sol = N[FullSimplify[({Q·x, Q·y, Q·z}·y)/Norm[Q]]];

ArcCos[sol]
```

Comment: So where is `φm` defined and I assume you want [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html?q=Dot)?

Comment: @gwr I have defined it after ClearAll. I want the inner product of two vectors and thats CenterDot or `ESC.ESC` I suppose.

Comment: Ah so it is center dot in the code too, then "CenterDot[x,y,\[Ellipsis]] has no built-in meaning."

Comment: Your original code has Theta not Phi... And now, if you replace [CenterDot] with `Dot` or `.` everything is fine: 0.916203.

Comment: @gwr yes that's my fault. look at the pure code.

Comment: @gwr http://s7.picofile.com/file/8254032118/2016_06_02_13_13_02_CenterDot_Wolfram_Mathematica_10_4.jpg

Comment: Yes, that is misleading, but it is simply explaining the use of a symbol in mathematical typesetting (could be for $\LaTeX$...). Try `?\[CenterDot]` and `?.`.

Comment: @AHB The highlighted part merely says the symbol is used to indicate the dot product in mathematics, not Mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion simply arises from mistaking a typesetting information for [`\[CenterDot]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/CenterDot.html) with the meaning of a symbol. Replacing `·` with `.` will solve the issue:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

r = (6.3674447) (10^6);
θm = (90 - 21.43) Degree;
ϕm = 39.82 Degree;
θe = (90 - 56.85) Degree;
ϕe = 60.6 Degree;

RM = {r Sin[θm] Cos[ϕm] , r Sin[θm] Sin[ϕm], r Cos[θm]};
RE = {r Sin[θe] Cos[ϕe] , r Sin[θe] Sin[ϕe], r Cos[θe]};

Q = FullSimplify[RM - RE];

x = {-Sin[ϕe], Cos[ϕe], 0};
y = {-Cos[θe] Cos[ϕe], -Cos[θe] Sin[ϕe], Sin[θe]};
z = x \[Cross] y;

sol = N[FullSimplify[({Q.x, Q.y, Q.z}.y)/Norm[Q]]];

ArcCos[sol]
```

> 0.916203

As [@Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116514/cant-get-a-numerical-value-for-this-vector-operation#comment316269_116514) has pointed out, the confusion ends reading [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CenterDot.html):

> [image: Blockquote]